# Проблемы с анимацией формы по нажатию кнопки

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть форма, в ней кнопка, которая обрабатывает введенные данные из формы. Есть CSS с анимацией этой формы.

Клик по кнопке

```
$('#btn_1').click(function(){$('#form1').toggleClass('animation')});
```

Если эта кнопка ВНЕ формы, то всё работает. Если в форме, то анимация прерывается через несколько милисекунд.

Как решить проблему, чтобы по нажатию кнопки и анимация нормально срабатывала, и данные из формы обрабатывались?

Comment: ну так приведите код формы сюда

Comment: Приведите код..

Comment: Вот в новом вопросе весь код https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/677673/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C