# Как это реализовать

Tags: php, javascript, css

1. Пользователь кликает по кнопке 1 в форме
2. Проверка введенных данных
3. Если проверка успешна -> анимация этой формы (переключение на 2 форму)
4. Кликаем по кнопке 2 и отправляем данные из двух форм в БД.

Как это сделать? Третий пункт вообще не понимаю как реализовать. 

Кроме того, здесь есть проблема, что анимация не работает нормально, если кнопка находится в форме. Если нажать на кнопку 3, то анимация работает. Но если она на форме (кнопка 1) то анимация прерывается.

**Вот сами формы, обработчики**

```
<div id="formsss">
        <div id="form_1">
            <h3>Форма 1</h3><br>
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <input name="input1" value="<?php echo $_POST['input1']; ?>"><br>
                    <?php

                    if ( isset($_POST['clicked_btn_1']) )
                    {

                        $errors = array();
                        if (trim($_POST['input1'] == ''))
                        {
                            $errors[] = 'Заполните поле';
                        }

                        if (R::count('test', 'input1 = ?', array($_POST['input1'])) > 0)
                        {
                            $errors[] = 'Такие данные уже есть в базе';
                        }

                        if (empty($errors))
                        {
                            // ПЕРЕКЛЮЧАЕМ НА ФОРМУ 2
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo '<div style="color: red;">'.array_shift($errors).'</div>';
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                <button id="btn_1" type="submit" name="clicked_btn_1">Кнопка 1</button>
            </form>
         </div>
         <div id="form_2">
            <h3>Форма 2</h3><br>
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <input name="input2" value="<?php echo $_POST[input2]; ?>"><br>
                <?php

                if ( isset($_POST['clicked_btn_2']) )
                {

                    $errors = array();
                    if (trim($_POST['input2'] == ''))
                    {
                        $errors[] = 'Заполните поле';
                    }

                    if (R::count('test', 'input2 = ?', array($_POST['input2'])) > 0)
                    {
                        $errors[] = 'Такие данные уже есть в базе';
                    }

                    if (empty($errors))
                    {
                        // заносим в базу данные из двух форм

                        $test = R::dispense('test');
                        $test->input1 = $_POST['input1'];
                        $test->input2 = $_POST['input2'];
                        R::store($test);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo '<div style="color: red;">'.array_shift($errors).'</div>';
                    }
                }
                ?>
                <button id="btn_2" type="submit" name="clicked_btn_2">Кнопка 2</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button id="btn_3" type="submit" name="clicked_btn_3">Кнопка 3</button>

    <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js">

     $('#btn_3').click(function(){
        $('#formsss').toggleClass('flipped')
    });
</script>
```

---

css анимация

```
#form_2{
-moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg)scale(.1)translateY(-70px);
-webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg)scale(.1)translateY(-70px);
-o-transform: rotateY(-180deg)scale(.1)translateY(-70px);
transform: rotateY(-180deg)scale(.1)translateY(-70px);
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
opacity: 0;
z-index: 1;
}

#form_2, #form_1 {
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-o-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-transition: .6s;
-webkit-transition: .6s;
-o-transition: .6s;
transition: 600ms 0ms;
transition-delay: 0.1s;
-o-transition-delay: 0.1s;
-webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
-moz-transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

#form_2 {
bottom: 20px;
top: 359px;
left: 20px;
right: 20px;
}

#form_2, pre {
position: absolute;
}

/*************************************************/

.flipped#formsss {
overflow: hidden;
}

.flipped #form_1 {
-moz-transform: rotateY(180deg)scale(.7);
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg)scale(.7);
-o-transform: rotateY(180deg)scale(.7);
transform: rotateY(180deg)scale(.7);
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
opacity: 0;
}

.flipped #form_2 {
-moz-transform: rotateY(0)scale(1);
-webkit-transform: rotateY(0)scale(1);
-o-transform: rotateY(0)scale(1);
transform: rotateY(0)scale(1);
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
opacity: 1;
z-index: 5;
display: block;
}
```

Comment: Я бы за такой код расстреливал на месте. Плюньте в лицо тому, кто научил вас так писать в 21-м веке.

Comment: @Squidward а как надо?

Comment: Для проверки первой кнопки используйте ajax-запрос к БД, потом уже после второй формы можно php выполнить дальше или так же ajax. И код ужасно выглядит у вас.
 <input name="input1" value="<?php echo $_POST[input1]; ?>" - это где такому учат? o_o

Comment: Не надо пихать HTML и PHP в один файл в виде нечитаемой каши, не надо писать монструозные `<?php echo` и при этом забывать экранирование, не надо именовать элементы управления от балды, не надо множить префиксы в CSS вручную. И у вас полное непонимание, что происходит на сервере и что на клиенте.

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте.

Используйте сессию. После заполнения первой формы сохраните проверенные данные в сессию и переходите на второй шаг, в котором вы указываете данные и также после успешной проверки отсылаете данные из сессии на обработку.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<div id="formsss">
<?
if(!isset($_SESSION['errors'])) {
?>
        <div id="form_1">
            <h3>Форма 1</h3><br>
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <input name="input1" value="<?php echo $_POST['input1']; ?>"><br>
                    <?php

                    if ( isset($_POST['clicked_btn_1']) )
                    {

                        $errors = array();
                        if (trim($_POST['input1'] == ''))
                        {
                            $errors[] = 'Заполните поле';
                        }

                        if (R::count('test', 'input1 = ?', array($_POST['input1'])) > 0)
                        {
                            $errors[] = 'Такие данные уже есть в базе';
                        }

                        if (empty($errors))
                        {
                            // ПЕРЕКЛЮЧАЕМ НА ФОРМУ 2, так как ошибок нет
                            $_SESSION['errors'] = 1;
                            $_SESSION['input1'] = $_POST['input1'];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            unset($_SESSION['errors']);
                            echo '<div style="color: red;">'.array_shift($errors).'</div>';
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                <button id="btn_1" type="submit" name="clicked_btn_1">Кнопка 1</button>
            </form>
         </div>
<?
}
if($_SESSION['errors']==1) {
?>
         <div id="form_2">
            <h3>Форма 2</h3><br>
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <input name="input2" value="<?php echo $_POST['input2']; ?>"><br>
                <?php

                if ( isset($_POST['clicked_btn_2']) )
                {

                    $errors = array();
                    if (trim($_POST['input2'] == ''))
                    {
                        $errors[] = 'Заполните поле';
                    }

                    if (R::count('test', 'input2 = ?', array($_POST['input2'])) > 0)
                    {
                        $errors[] = 'Такие данные уже есть в базе';
                    }

                    if (empty($errors))
                    {
                        // заносим в базу данные из двух форм

                        $test = R::dispense('test');
                        //$test->input1 = $_POST['input1'];
                        $test->input1 = $_SESSION['input1'];
                        $test->input2 = $_POST['input2'];
                        R::store($test);
                        unset($_SESSION['errors']);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $_SESSION['errors'] = 1;
                        echo '<div style="color: red;">'.array_shift($errors).'</div>';
                    }
                }
                ?>
                <button id="btn_2" type="submit" name="clicked_btn_2">Кнопка 2</button>
            </form>
        </div>
<?
}
?>
</div>
    <button id="btn_3" type="submit" name="clicked_btn_3">Кнопка 3</button>

<script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js">

     $('#btn_3').click(function(){
        $('#formsss').toggleClass('flipped')
    });
</script>
```

Comment: по-моему, автору нужно через javascript

Comment: А для чего он использует подстановку из первой формы с помощью  PHP?

Comment: < ? p h p   echo $ _ P O S T [ i n p u t 1 ] ; ? >

Comment: а как отобразить форму в анимации?

Comment: Извиняюсь за опечатку в проверки условия, должны быть два знака равно. У вас в коде разбито на две формы. Вам нужно переделать проверку. У вас проверка введенных данных производится внутри формы которую вы ещё не заполнили и не отправили. И вторую форму выводить после проверки на ошибки введенных данных в первой форме. Третья кнопка вынесенна за пределы формы и ей нет смысла указывать тип submit. Код поправил под ваше вариант. Может это вас устроит.

Comment: @Vladimir спасибо, но это не то. Третья кнопка нужна лишь для примера (потому что она работает). Если сделать клик на кнопку 1, то анимация работает некорректно, прерывается через несколько милисекунд. Смена форм должна происходить не с помощью php, как вы сделали, а через CSS с анимацией. Я добавил в свой код сессии и данные в БД теперь записываются корректно. Но единственное что не работает, это анимированное переключение форм кнопкой 1 (кнопкой 3 работает). Здесь надо в условии пхп как-то задействовать этот код `$('#formsss').toggleClass('flipped'),` но он опять же некорректно работает

Comment: Нет, пропишите обработчик не только для третьей кнопки но и для первой и второй, тогда анимация будет при нажатии любой кнопки.

Comment: @Vladimir прописал естественно, но она не работает